# Strange divots on mesh located?

Tags: mesh, edges, normals

I was looking through this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24hUk1Xjtog) speed model by blend motion, and it inspired me to create a similar combat style knife. In blend motion's video the blade had similar bumpy issues however they seemed to just fix themselves somehow, this was not the case for me.

With Subsurf:[image: With Subsurf]

Without Subsurf[image: Without Subsurf]

However the blade has got strange divots on the serrated side of the blade, these divots create an unwanted bumpy look to the model.

Without Subsurf:[image]

I have tried moving the inner and outer edges on the x and y axis; also scaling the sides on the Y axis by zero to try and flatten the edge, to try and stop this (this did nothing), I also experimented with the normal directions to see if that was the problem, though this did not fix anything.

Example of tipology's (without sub divisions)
Front:[image: Front]

Front(zoomed on to bump):[image: Front(zoomed on to bump)]

Serrated edge side:[image: Serrated-edge-side]

Serrated edge side(zoomed):[image: Serrated-edge-side(zoomed)]

I want to use this model for a game-engine but these bumpy parts of the mesh stick out like a saw thumb. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: please share your file  https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BDj2b1e6" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BDj2b1e6/) This is the .blend file

Comment: If you manage to fix this, a walkthrough of your workflow would be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hi! Please follow these steps*

**STEP 1**

I changed the lighting of the mesh to matcap and chose a charcoal black colour so we can spot the bad shading easily.Then I tweaked the geometry of a few faces by deleted them and reconstructing them.
[image]

**STEP 2**

Then I added and deleted some edge loops, added the subdivision surface modifier and then increased the levels of subdivision to 2.

[image]

Hope this worked :)

**Final Result:**

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you very much, this is a great help!

Comment: your welcome! happy to help :)